# Nomad+Docker: Using the local Docker image, avoiding cleanup

Tags: docker, docker-image, nomad

## My problem

I use nomad to schedule and deploy Docker images across several nodes. I am using a pretty stable image, so I want that image to be loaded locally rather than fetched from Dockerhub each time.

The [`docker.cleanup.image`](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker.html#docker-cleanup-image) argument should do just that:

> `docker.cleanup.image` Defaults to true. Changing this to false will prevent Nomad from removing images from stopped tasks, which is exactly what I want.

The documentation example is:

```
client {
  options {
    "docker.cleanup.image" = "false"
  }
}
```

However, I don't know where this stanza goes. I tried placing it in the `job` or `task` sections of the fairly simple configuration file, with no success.

## Code (configuration file)

```
job "example" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"
  update {
    max_parallel = 30
    min_healthy_time = "10s"
    healthy_deadline = "3m"
    auto_revert = false
    canary = 0
  }
  group "cache" {
    count = 30
    restart {
      attempts = 10
      interval = "5m"
      delay = "25s"
      mode = "delay"
    }
    ephemeral_disk {
      size = 300
    }
    task "redis" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
    image = "whatever/whatever:v1"
        port_map {
          db = 80
        }
      }
      env {
    "LOGGER" = "ec2-52-58-216-66.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
      }
      resources {
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "db" {}
        }
      }
      service {
        name = "global-redis-check"
        tags = ["global", "cache"]
        port = "db"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## My question

**Where do I place the `client` stanza in the nomad configuration file?**

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't go in your job file, it goes on the nomad agents (the clients where nomad jobs are deployed).